# SQL Server using order by clause significantly improves select performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing the following query directly in SQL Server:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB 
       ON TableB.field1 = TableA.field1
LEFT JOIN TableC 
       ON TableC.field2 = TableA.field2
LEFT JOIN TableD 
       ON TableD.field3 = TableA.field3
LEFT JOIN TableE 
       ON TableE.field4 = TableA.field4
LEFT JOIN TableF 
       ON TableF.field5 = TableA.field5
LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT *
             FROM 
                (SELECT 
                       Id1, Id2,
                       UpdateDate,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id1, Id2, 
               ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) AS RN 
                   FROM TableG) AS G 
           WHERE G.RN = 1) TableH 
     ON TableA.Id1 = TableH.Id2 
    AND TableA.Id1 = TableH.Id2
```

For point of reference, Table A-F and G are about 1000 rows, and Table G is about 10000 rows.

For a particular input, this query takes about 1 minute to run.

I then add a

```
ORDER BY Id1 ASC
```

at the end of the statement, and now it takes about 6 seconds to run. How can adding a sort significantly improve performance like this?

Comment: It could be cached. Run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` on a non production system to clear the cache. Is the query plan different between the two? How many records are returned and are you waiting for them all?

Comment: Given the `LEFT JOIN`s, I find it very surprising that a sort on the first table could ever improve performance.  Your `JOIN` conditions on `H` are suspect as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run a showplan on both versions of your query.

Probably what's happening is the sort forces a different query plan, which uses a more efficient for your particular data join strategy (probably in-memory), but which has a higher estimated cost.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the execution plan, it seems that the issue was with the JOIN on Table A and Table G. Initially the optimizer was trying to use a nested loop join which was very inefficient for tables of their size. Adding the ORDER BY clause hinted to the optimizer to use a merge join instead, which was much faster. Thanks for the answers!